# Did Lord Shiva really offer his testicles to Maa Parvati in Padma Purana?

Tags: shiva, puranas, parvati, padma-purana

Is this actually true?

asvāditaṃ na cānyena bhakṣyārthe ca dadāmyaham |
adhobhāge ca me nābhervartulau phalasannibhau || 126 ||
bhakṣayadhvaṃ hi sahitā laṃbau me vṛṣaṇāvimau |
anena cāpi bhojyena parā tṛptirbhaviṣyati || 127 ||

126-127. "I shall give you as food which has never been
tasted before by anyone. Below my navel are these two circular
long and fruit-like testicles. Even with this food you will have
great satisfaction.”

Padma Purana, Srishti Khanda, Chapter 31, 126-127

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's *true* or not, but it's definitely canonical. That is, the line does in fact appear in all the genuine versions of the Padma Purana. This includes the original Sanskrit version and the translations, though some of the translations try to get around mentioning it explicitly by using euphemisms. The Sanskrit word for 'testicle' is *vṛṣaṇā*, which appears as part of the word *vṛṣaṇāvimau* ([Source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=v%E1%B9%9B%E1%B9%A3a%E1%B9%87%C4%81&dir=au)). The translation that you found was definitely an accurate one.

Here's the full version of the one you're quoting, provided by [Wisdom Lib:](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364152.html)

> 122. For these goddesses give me food which is inaccessible in heaven, which is oily, mixed with jaggery, tasty and well-cooked and which is intended for them, and which is not enjoyed by anyone else before, O great god.
> 123. Thus addressed Maheśvara, the god of gods, told them in the vicinity of Pārvatī about their food:
> 124. “I have accomplished the food prepared in many ways. All that is exhausted. And no other (kind of food) is seen here.
> 125. Tell me what I should today give to you who have come (to me). I have especially to give something quite new.
>
> 126-127. I shall give you as food which has never been tasted before by anyone. Below my navel are these two circular long and fruit-like testicles. Even with this food you will have great satisfaction.
>
> 128. Receiving that great favour all the goddesses saluted Śiva. Śarva said these words to them:
>
> 129-130. “The wealth, beasts, sons, wives and houses etc. of those who perform auspicious deeds without laughing, will be given to you by me; and also whatever else is in your mind. Those who by laughing have long teeth (i.e. show their teeth) (will) become poor.
>
> 131. Therefore, one who is wise, should not indulge in censuring or laughing (at others). In this world you will be known as mothers.
>
> 132-133a. The lineage of those men, who, along with their relatives and kinsmen, prepare (articles from) a lotus, grams, and also cakes and sorts of bread with (i.e. having the shape of) testicles, as an offering, is not cut off.
>
> 133b-134. A man who has no son, gets a son; he, who desires wealth, obtains it; he, being handsome, lucky, enjoyer, well-versed in all sciences, is honoured in Brahmā’s world with (i.e. being taken in) a vehicle to which swans are yoked.
>
> 135. O Śivadūtī, thus I have given them food. Does it bring shame to you?

I don't know what you mean by 'true,' but if your question is whether or not this story genuinely appears in the Padma Purana, the answer is: it does. This isn't a random story that somebody snuck in.

Nice question, though!

Comment: Is there a reason as to why he'd say this? Doesn't this show the characteristics of "Kaam"? Or is there a deeper/symbolic meaning behind this exchange? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: @lexion - I'll update my answer with what I find- I do think that there is a deeper significance to it, I'm just unsure as to what it is. I'll keep searching.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't help but notice the {GL_NOTE::} next to the very verse in question (check on wisdomlib). In PDF's there is a "1" next to it, however no description whatsoever. There probably is an explanation for such thing that is not added

Comment: @lexion - [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Padma_Purana_Srishti_Khanda_Part_1_Engli/dj9KEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=padma+purana+shiva+parvati+testicles&pg=PT634&printsec=frontcover) version includes the note- but unfortunately, the note is completely irrelevant to what we're trying to figure out :(

Comment: Oh damn. I did come across this one but I think this is actually referring to verse 118-121, not the one in question.

Comment: @lexion - yeah, I think you're right. So... idk. There doesn't seem to be any other information about this anywhere.

Comment: My friend actually asked from an Advaitin who has a Telegram for clarifying such things, maybe we'll get our answer from there. Will keep you posted. Thanks a lot

Comment: @lexion - good to know, please do, no problem :)

Comment: We got a response from one of their students. Some grammatical errors but it's understandable:
यहाँ शिवदूती देवी द्वारा शिव के अण्डकोष के भक्षण का विषय कहा जाता है। ब्रह्माण्ड को भी अण्डकोष कहते हैं। अट्टहासभिन्नपद्मजाण्डकोषसन्ततिम् ।

जब विश्वरूप का वर्णन करते हैं तो द्यौस्ते शीर्ष - आकाश आपका मस्तक है, ऐसा कहते हैं, इस अनुसार पृथ्वी शिव की नाभि है और नाभि के नीचे, पृथ्वी के नीचे के लोक असुरों के हैं।

अत: देवी शिवदूती द्वारा तलाताल तथा सुताल निवासी असुरो के भक्षण का आहार प्रतिपदान किया गया है, (अत: इन्ही दोनों असुरलोको को इस स्थानपे महेश्वर के 2 अंडकोष द्वारा प्रतिनिधितव कय गय ह) ।

Comment: contd..
यह प अडकष क परयग, पड हत कय गय ह, य पड बरहमणड क सवरप भ हत ह । अत: दवललओ स अलकत वकय म पड, बरहमणड एव अडकष क एकतव मनन चहए । परणक गरथ पर कछ टककर क भषय अनसर, मतर इस शलक म ह नह अपत गरथ म अडकष क अरथ सजञ वशष परष अग (वषण:) हत नह कय गय ह। दवभष ससकत म, वषण: क अरथ परष अगवशष स हत ह, अपत अडकष क अरथ बरहमणड, पड तथ लक स हत ह। 

अडकश - अड, फत, बज, बरहमड, वशव-मडल, लक, सम, हद, फल क ऊपर छलक ।

परष अग क ससकत म  वषण कहत ह।

हर हर महदव

Comment: @lexion - that's a much quicker response than I was expecting! It seems that we really did need an explanation from somebody who has studied more extensively. I'm glad you managed to figure it out 